# php recursive looping not repeat divider

Tags: php

I have problem with recrusive looping. I have db table `site_pages` where i store web pages (cms) and that pages can have parent whitch is related with `parent_id` in the some table.

Generally want to achieve this effect with these retractable.

`|—` if is root if has one children

`|—|—` if has two children

`|—|—|—` three childrens ...

[image]

Above is effect what i want. But in my case i get this effect. There is not repeated two dividers before page title.

[image]

Here is my array what i loop :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Home
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => About us
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [title] => Subpage #1                
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                            [title] => Subpage #2                                     
                                        )


                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

**Code where i loop `pages` array:**

```
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Page name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php if($pages): ?>

                        <?php foreach ($pages as $index => $page): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="gi">|—</span><?= $page['title'];?></td>
                                <td><?= $page['status'];?></td>
                                <td>N/A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php if(!empty($page['children'])): ?>
                                <?= fetchChilds($page['children']); ?>
                            <?php endif;?>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**And here is child looping helper function:**

```
function fetchChilds($pages) {

    $html = "<tr>";

    foreach ($pages as $child) {

        $html .= '<td> <span class="gi">|—</span>'. $child["title"] .'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'. $child["status"] .'</td>';
        $html .= '<td> N/A</td>';

        if(isset($child['children'])) {
            $html .=  fetchChilds($child['children']);
        }
    }

    $html .= "</tr>";

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no repeated divider in the output. Because every table row (why do you use tables for this?) contains only the one |- prefix.

Without complety rewriting your code, the only idea I have is to add a level-param to fetchChilds.

```
function fetchChilds($pages, $level) {

    foreach ($pages as $child) {
        $html = "<tr>";
        $html .= '<td> <span class="gi">'. str_repeat("|-", $level); .'</span>'. $child["title"] .'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'. $child["status"] .'</td>';
        $html .= '<td> N/A</td>';
        $html .= "</tr>";

        if(isset($child['children'])) {
            $html .=  fetchChilds($child['children'], $level+1);
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
```

And then you need to add a level to your other code:

```
<?php if($pages): ?>
   <?php foreach ($pages as $index => $page): ?>
       <tr>
           <td><span class="gi">|—</span><?= $page['title'];?></td>
           <td><?= $page['status'];?></td>
           <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <?php if(!empty($page['children'])): ?>
            <?= fetchChilds($page['children'],2); ?>
        <?php endif;?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you make that step, you might realize that your topmost array level is level 1 and could be used in fetchChilds as well:

```
<?php if($pages): ?>
   <?php foreach ($pages as $index => $page): ?>
       <?= fetchChilds($page,1); ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This work perfect if has one child. If i have two childs or more `<tr>` was not added and everything is inline. Example `aboutus > sub #1 > sub #2 > sub 3` every think is inline `<td>aboutus <td><td>sub 1</td><td>sub 2</td>` no `tr` tag added. But if i has only one child tr is added

Comment: Your right. I changed to fetchChild function. The <tr></tr> structure needs to be in the foreach before calling another fetchChild. Please try this.